# JavaScript : window.open() function opening link in new window instead of proving same window name in IE7

Tags: javascript, dom-events, javascript-framework

I have two buttons (A & B) on a page which opens a new window on click. Both the buttons are using same JavaScript function and the windowName is passed dynamically (`_AWindow` is passed for button A and `_BWindow`is passed for button B).

JavaScript code to open window is:

```
window.open(s_url,windowName);
```

I am facing following strange problem.

If I click on button A first time then it opens link(https://www.) in a new window(name : _AWindow) and again clicking the same button opens the link in existing window.

**BUT**

If I click on button B first time then it opens link(https://secure. ) in a new window (name : _BWindow) but again clicking the button B it again opens a new window instead of opening link in same window.

I am using IE7 version 7.0.5730.13

Please help!

Comment: Can you post a bit more of the code in here, in theory what you are doing seems fine but lets look at the actual implementation

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a global variable with the name "name" in the page opening in `_BWindow`? Changing the value of the global would rename the window, causing the second launch to fail.